# How to deploy approval process using ANT/Eclipse in salesforce

Tags: eclipse, ant, salesforce

I am trying to deploy approval process to cutomer Production orgs. It is difficult to do the manual creation of approval in each customer org. Anybody know this can be done by ANT/Eclipse ? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you ask this question on salesforce.stackexchange.com? Community is dedicated to salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Ant for deployment SF-apps you also need Ant-plugin - ant-salesforce.jar. So you can use the following script in build.xml

```
<project name="ExampleProject" default="ExampleProject" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" classPath="ant-salesforce.jar" uri="antlib:com.salesforce"/>
<target name="ExampleProject">
    <sf:deploy deployRoot="Application/src" username="your_sf_username" password="your_sf_password_and_token" serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com" runAllTests="true" rollbackOnError="true" />
</target>
</project>
```

(It's just an example, not working script)

Also you can use Eclipse with SF-plugin, which allow to deploy SF-apps and parts of them (also approval processes) to sandboxes. This plugin also has a lot of other useful functions.